# How to disable dirty checking in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Here is a simple code.

I get some Entity from **DataBase** through ***JPA repository***, do some logic and do not want Hibernate to save it for me:

```
      @GetMapping("/{id}")
      @Transactional
      public ERespondent getRespondent(@PathVariable Long id) {
          var entity= respondentRepository.findById(id).get();
          entity.setFirstName("weqweqwdq");
          // other logic here..
          return entity;
      }
```

Set FlushMode in the config file to `MANUAL` and still see that hibernate does update at the end.

Do I need to do it in one transaction to initiate lazy load collection?

I want to manage my entity by myself and don't want that hibernate to do overhead work like save a copy of the entity in the cache -> check it out for changes -> save it to DB.

Answer (score 3):

I know 3 options

1. mark transaction as read-only:

`@Transactional(readOnly = true)`

2. detach the entity first:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
public ERespondent getRespondent(@PathVariable Long id) {
    var entity= respondentRepository.findById(id).get();
    em.detach(entity); //now it is disconnected from persistence and becomes +- POJO
    entity.setFirstName("weqweqwdq");
    // some other logic
    return entity;
}
```

3. Copy the whole object modify and return the copy:

```
@Transactional
public ERespondent getRespondent(@PathVariable Long id) {
    var entity= respondentRepository.findById(id).get();
    copy=new EResponsend(entity); // you have to implement copy constructor
    copy.setFirstName("weqweqwdq");
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: to detach entity i need to use EntityManager - it means i need to generate billions boilerplate code .I need to do it for whole application ,not for one method only

Comment: copy entity is not good idea - i want to disable it -because hibernate do it by itself

Comment: @Transactioanl(readOnly=true) its not good idea too,because you cant save enity by yourself then.But all i need it save entity by myself if i want and do not want to do same by Hibernate - I need to disable dirty checking,nothing more....

Comment: Do you want to disable it compleatly applicationwise and never turn it back on again? I was thinking of incidental detachement. After all, JPA is there to actually manage entities, not only to hydrate POJOs with SQL results

Comment: As for detaching via entity manager - you can write aspect to detach objects where needed (its not clear what are your criterias of when to do it and when to dont)

Comment: Yes i want to disable dirty cheking for  applicationwise and never turn it back on again.If you know how to do it please help me with that

Comment: How about writing aspect that will detach entity after repository method invocations?

Comment: sounds good how to do it?but better do turn of dirty cheking

Comment: I dont know if that is even possible.

Comment: Do @Transactioal( readOnly=true) disable dirty checking,that means not only save enitity is not available,its about stop cheking cnanges of entity,stop copy them to persistens context ,etc? am i right?

Comment: Yes, no transaction will be commited.

Comment: but if i do @Transactioal( readOnly=true) ,entity still managed and its not ok -the copy of it still in persistence context.I cheked it out with em.contains( entity) and got true-that not rly good  because it still spending memory and other resourses.

Comment: Sure, the thing is you didnt specify rationale behind this. I have concluded from the snippet that you want to simply modify peristent entity without saving the changes.

Comment: its not about modify - i need to get lazy loaded collections - its only able in transaction,but also in this transaction hibernate do copy of all entities and i guess it checked they states at the end- and its not good for perfomance.Thats why i want to disable dirty cheking - its realy worst thing i saw in IT and no way to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

You can write an interceptor that clears the entity manager. Then you just annotate a top level class with the interceptor annotation or however this works with Spring (maybe see this article https://www.baeldung.com/cdi-interceptor-vs-spring-aspectj) and should be good to go. Depending on how well you separate your code, you might have to put it on individual methods rather than on class level though or consider splitting code between "read-only" and "write" code paths. I usually do this by moving this "read-only" code into so called `DataAccess` classes and the "write" code into `Service` classes.